# How to unlink dll from exe

Tags: windows, dll, exe

I don't know if this is a duplicate, anyway I have Google searched extensively and found absolutely nothing relevant.

The problem is extremely simple, I have an .exe file, this .exe file loads another .dll file when it runs, said .dll file isn't essential to the function of the .exe file, and I want to prevent the .exe file from loading the .dll file.

For more context, the .exe file is the executable of a game I downloaded from igg-games.com and the .dll file in question is IGG-GAMES.COM.dll, it creates two useless url shortcuts each time I run the game. (So obviously I don't have the source code)

Deleting the .dll results in System Error when trying to run the game. The .dll is injected into the executable, and what I intend to do is exactly the opposite of .dll injecting, I want to unlink the .dll from the .exe/remove the reference of the .dll from the .exe/delete the dependency of the .dll from the .exe/whatever you call it, how can this be done?

I can see the dependencies using [PEInfo](https://pazera-software.com/products/peinfo/) and [Dependecies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), but obviously these tools don't let me modify the exe file, I just want to delete said .dll from the import section of the .exe.

---

For whatever it is worth, I haven't gained useful information here. So I took drastic approach, I have already seen the import section texts in PEInfo, so I opened the .exe file in HxD, located the import header texts by searching, and replaced the relevant bytes with zeros, and then saved the .exe file.

It worked, there were no problems. But as comments have pointed out this isn't a general solution that works for every situation, so I want to know the proper way to do this.

Comment: "I don't have the source code". "The problem is extremely simple." ... But its not is it. You'll need the source code to make your changes, and to recompile the application.

Comment: @GetSet Nope, I don't need the source code, igg-games.com doesn't have the source code either, it injected the .dll, and if injecting the .dll into existing portable executable without source code is possible, then the reverse must also be true.

Comment: ok, you can remove `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` for this dll, from exe. in this case dll will be not loaded, but if exe call any function from this dll, will be crash. you can replace dll to self, which will be export the same functions, as original dll, and this functions will be "empty". are this will be work or no, depend from functions. if exe wait that some api return pointer and will be use it than, you again got crash. without understanding what every function must return.. at all what concrete you need ?

Comment: The source code I'm talking about is not to the dll itself but to the exe that links to the dll.

Comment: The simplest way would be to develop an own dummy DLL that provide that export the same functions but just does nothing. Then you could replace the DLL with your dummy DLL. You just have to check what data type you have to return in each exported function. For that a tool like Ghidra may be helpful.

Comment: @Robert Does programming language matter? Is it as long as the .dll is a valid .dll that exposes functions with the same names and return types, and with the same bitness as the .exe, what programming language I use doesn't matter?

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Best would be the same language as the original DLL. Assuming it was created using C/C++ that would be the best option. I am not sure how important the "Calling Conventions" of the different programming languages are if you don't do anything in the DLL functions. As the Community Editions of Visual Studio are free to use I would start with them and create a DLL fro C code.

Answer (score 0):

If it is small you can try to **decompile** the exe and remove the dll loading from the code or replace the function call.
You can use :
[ghidra on github](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/releases)

The other option as mentioned, is to compile your own .dll providing the function needed by the exe.